# How can i fix the dock widget to the the Qgis window using python

Tags: qgis, pyqt

I am creating a dock widget for my plugin and i want my widget to be fixed to the Qgis window. How can i do that using python programming?

Answer (score 4):

This question is perhaps better suited to StackOverflow, as it doesn't specifically relate to GIS (other than that the application you're using is QGIS).

To create a new dock widget and add it to the left panel:

```
dockwidget = QtGui.QDockWidget(iface.mainWindow())
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dockwidget)
```

If the user moves it to a floating window you can then re-dock it using `setFloating`:

```
dockwidget.setFloating(False)
```

If you want to prevent the user from moving it to a floating window you need to set the "features" of the widget. In the example below, the widget is movable and closable, but not floatable:

```
dockwidget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable | QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
```

Comment: I have created DockWidget using QT designer and chosen the options as QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable | QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable. But when i am calling in my plugin it is not getting fixed to the table space?

Comment: Does calling `setFloating` not have any effect?

Comment: No I have selected/deselected Floating option in QT designer itself but it doesnot show any effect.